# Event SourcePost doesn't exist

Tags: vimrc, autocmd

While searching for autocommands event I noticed that there are no `SourcePost` event. This is strange, because nearly all of other event have a `Post` version of it (e.g. `FileAppendPost`, `BufWritePost`, ... ).

Do you know the reason behind this ?

Comment: It was probably not needed when creating it

Comment: Maybe because you can exit Vim by sourcing?

Comment: @muru: what do you mean ?

Comment: @Nobe4 if I have `wqa!` in a file and I source it, Vim will quit, right? With most other events, it's quite unlikely that Vim will exit unless there's a fatal error. So there's no way to be reasonably sure if Vim can get commands to run after sourcing.

Comment: @muru: OK I see your point, a summary could be that `SourcePost` was not provided because the sourcing could quit Vim? Do you know if there is a method to do the event "catching" manually ? e.g. execute a methode after the sourcing of a file (if vim is still open obviously)

Comment: Excuse me for interjecting, but I don't think being able to quit makes any sense as an explanation. Any script can quit.  Any normal `autocmd` can also quit. So what? What's wrong with that? What's right about not doing it? Rather, I don't see any use for a `SourcePost`.  `SourcePre` could be useful for debugging.  Overriding `SourceCmd` could be useful for things like fetching the script from a remote location, and then you'd also be able to add code afterwards.  But adding code without overriding `SourceCmd`?  I can't really think of any useful scenario.

Comment: @SatoKatsura: I thought about a function in the vimrc that would be called after sourcing the vimrc.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense.  Sourcing is a pretty special thing to do, you normally want `runtime` instead.  And you can always define a `SourceCmd`, that sources `<afile>` and runs your function. _shrug_

Comment: Well maybe it's me that have trouble understanding why it doesn't make sens ^^ But yes the `SourceCmd` would be a good workaround :) Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Old one, but this has been added as per [patch 8.1.0729](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/2b6185287adf53343ed5f49e967ae402c64063e4)

> Problem:    There is a SourcePre autocommand event but not a SourcePost.
> Solution:   Add the SourcePost autocommand event. (closes [#3739](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3739))